# KotlinでC++のstd::any_ofに相当する標準関数はありますか？

Tags: kotlin

https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/any_of.html

Iteratorの各要素に条件式を適用し、trueを返した時点で残りの走査を打ち切って結果の真偽値を返す、ということをしたいです。
std::none_of, std::all_ofに相当するものもあれば同時に紹介いただきたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それぞれ以下が対応すると思います。

- [any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html)
- [all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html)
- [none](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/none.html)